# Создать бинарный файл (spring приложение)

Tags: java, spring

Не могу создать бинарный файл.

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

Например в resources лежит `application.properties` и получаю я его так

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
```

Но как записать в эту же директорию файл?
Делаю так.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Files.bin");
ObjectOutputStream serial = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
serial.writeObject(filesFound);
serial.flush();
fos.close();
serial.close();
```

Но ничего не происходит и файла ни где нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом создавать файл, внизу в консоли выведется путь, где создан файл.

```
    File file = new File ("Files.bin");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream serial = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    serial.writeObject(filesFound);
    serial.flush();
    fos.close();
    serial.close();

    System.out.println("Путь к созданному файлу: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Дополнение, для того, чтоб можно было получить файл из приложения запущенного в Tomcat, я использовал такой способ:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String method(HttpServletRequest request) {

    File file = null;

    try {
        ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        String realContextPath = context.getRealPath(request.getContextPath());

        System.out.println("realContextPath" + realContextPath);

        file = new File(realContextPath + "/WEB-INF/Files.bin");

        //это маленький колстыль, чтоб можно было запускать из иде и в томкате
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            realContextPath = context.getRealPath("");
            file = new File(realContextPath + "/WEB-INF/Files.bin");
        }

        //тут можем работать с file

        System.out.println("Files.bin is found = " + file.isFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: Это я попробовал, он его создает в c:\eclipse. Т.е в ide. А при деплое проекта в какую директорию он может создать файл? WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: Смотря куда деплоите, если это томкат, то `TOMCAT_HOME/bin`

Comment: Ну хоть так. А вообще можно как то указать на resources? Не прописывая абсолютный путь

Comment: @Kleimosc , а Вы не пробовали пример отсюда? [ссылка](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) 
Первый пример. 
В строке `new FileOutputStream("config.properties");` заменить на `new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/Files.bin");`

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте его. @CheshireK Ваш вариант не будет работать, т.к. приложение запускается в контейнере Tomcat, а не в main.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid Scheduled method 'createBinaryFile': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled. Я использую планировщик и не могу в метод поместить   HttpServletRequest request. В планировщике и создается файл

Comment: File file = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "Files.bin");  Вот он красавец

Comment: Только домой добрался, видел такой вариант, но не проверял, и теперь попробую)) Только не забудьте, что при редепое приложения, файлы в ресурсах могут потеряться, будьте аккуратны.